# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer settings for SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Ruby On Rails app configured for SSL only, and set up the following listener on my elastic load balancer:

[image]

With this configuration, my site application does not resolve, and I don't understand why. If however, I change the instance protocol to HTTP everything works as expected.

Could someone explain why this is please?

Comment: Did you configure the port at the Beanstalk level? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html

Answer (score 1):

When configuring an ELB to listen on HTTPS, you must upload a certificate to IAM and link it from the ELB.

Procedure is [described in the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_UpdatingLoadBalancerSSL.html)

When using AWS ElasticBeanstalk, you can also configure your ELB and SSL certificate from a `config` file located in your `source's home/.ebextensions`

Sample config file is :

```
 - namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
   option_name: LoadBalancerHTTPSPort
   value: 443

 - namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
   option_name: SSLCertificateId
   value: arn:aws:iam::012345678901:server-certificate/my_certificate_name
```

Have a look at [the detailed documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-options) for possible options

Comment: @sebsta - Thanks for the reply. My ELB listens fine on HTTPS, it's just the hop from ELB to the instance that does not work with HTTPS.

Comment: I would verify a couple of things : #1/ is your HTTPS listener correctly configured and woking on the instance itself ?  #2 / Did you open your Security Group for ELB HTTPS traffic ?

Comment: #1 probably not, I have no idea how to do this, where is the menu option please? #2 yes, i did